# List the installed (attached) artifacts of a build

Tags: maven, gitlab-ci

For the gitlab ci release page, I need a list of all artifacts that installed/deployed in a given build.

So something like:

- I run `mvn clean deploy`
- Afterwards I can read the list from some file